# QTableView: how do I correctly create a QModelIndex?

Tags: qt, qtableview, qmodelindex

I'm trying to enter edit mode on a specific cell like this:

```
void MainWindow::on_addButton_released() {
    tm->addRow();
    tableView->scrollToBottom();
    int ec=tm->firstWritableColumn();
    int r=tm->rowCount(QModelIndex());
    QModelIndex id = tm->index(r, ec, QModelIndex());
    tableView->setCurrentIndex(id);
    tableView->edit(id);
    qDebug() << "row:" << r << " col:" << ec << "index:" << id;
}
```

My model creates an index like this:

```
QModelIndex TableModel::index(int row,int column,QModelIndex parent) const {
    Q_UNUSED(parent);
    return createIndex(row,column,0);
}
```

The debug output looks like this:

```
row: 9  col: 1 index: QModelIndex(9,1,0x0,TableModel(0xbf3f50) )
```

I'm fairly sure that the index is somehow invalid as `setCurrentIndex()` doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Your `index()` method doesn't actually override anything (`QModelIndex` vs. `const QModelIndex &`). Copy-paste error?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

OMG! ground swallow me up!

row numbers start with row 0, I needed to do

```
int r=tm->rowCount(QModelIndex())-1;
QModelIndex id=tm->index(r,ec,QModelIndex());
```

Comment: I forget this constantly with widget toolkits, so I try never to use `row` or `column` alone.  Instead, I use `rowIndex` (for zero-based) and, much more rarely, `rowNumber` (for one-based).

Comment: 'tm' must be the table model over here??